# Template member function specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I have this:

```
//forward declaration
template<typename Elem, int D1 = 1, int D2 = 1, int D3 = 1>
class matrix;

template<typename Elem, int D1, int D2, int D3>
struct matrix_deref_type_trait
{
    typedef matrix<Elem, D2 == 1 ? 1 : D1, D3 == 1 ? 1 : D2, 1> matrix_deref;
};

template<typename Elem, int D1>
struct matrix_deref_type_trait<Elem, D1, 1, 1>
{
    typedef Elem matrix_deref;
};

template<typename Elem, int D1, int D2, int D3>
class matrix:public object
{
public:
    typedef typename matrix_deref_type_trait<Elem, D1, D2, D3>::matrix_deref matrix_deref;

    inline matrix_deref operator[](int J)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And want to specialize a case for the operator[] (outside the class body):

```
template<typename Elem, int D1>
typename matrix<Elem, D1, 1, 1>::matrix_deref matrix<Elem, D1, 1, 1>::operator[](int J)
{
    return M_ptr[J];
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
error C2244: 'matrix<Elem,D1,D2,D3>::operator []' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
```

Can I override this member function without full specialization of the whole class? What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: @Nik It's only a irrelevant pointer... I delete those declarations from the class to make the problem clear.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot specialize a non-template method of a template class. You can only specialize a template class itself. Or you can specialize template method of any (template or non-template class).

Specializing non-template method of a template class makes no sense: compiler needs to know how the whole class looks. And you're just telling: hey, I don't care about the class, but what I know is how this one method will look like.

Comment: Templates is very tricky tool. It is too easy to make complicated and unreadable code.

Answer (score 2):

just specialize you matrix class :

```
template<typename Elem, int D1>
class matrix<Elem,D1,1,1>
{
public:
    typedef typename matrix_deref_type_trait<Elem, D1, 1, 1>::matrix_deref matrix_deref;//this line 

    inline matrix_deref operator[](int J)
    {
        std::cout << "special\n";
    }
};
```

also you dont need to do the `?:` check in trait class, because if `D2` and `D3` are `1` it will always choose the trait specialization.

Comment: But I think I will need to copy-and-paste other members to the specialization (there are a bunch of them)

Comment: so it will be a copy paste + removing the D2 and D3 type parameters and replacng with the constants. i dont think it will be so lengthy?

Comment: I think the D2 and D3 are necessary because it should support up to 3-d matrix

Comment: no in the specialization y would you need? you are specializing for a case where D2 and D3 are 1 anyways right?

Comment: Ah I get what you mean. Thanks:) Seems it's the only way